# Incorrect scopes returned from Xero getClientCredentialsToken

Tags: xero-api

I am using xero-node to connect to the Xero API. Following the documentation, I have

```
this._instance = new XeroClient({
  clientId:     CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: CLIENT_SECTRET,
  grantType:    'client_credentials',
  scopes:       ['accounting.transactions','accounting.contacts'],
});
```

When I then call `const tokenSet = await this._instance.getClientCredentialsToken();` the scopes that are returned with the access token are `app.connections marketplace.billing` (neither of the two that were requested).

So I get 403 Forbidden errors whenever I try to call any of the accountingAPI endpoints that are included in the initial scope set. I've tried adding `await this._instance.initialize()` in before and after the call to get the access token, but it doesn't change the result.

Am I missing something from the docs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xero-node#custom-connections and https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/client-credentials)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the type of app you have created in developer.xero.com?

one reason you would get the issue would be if you have created a web app rather than a custom connection app.

Requesting tokens for a web app needs the authorization grant type.

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/auth-flow

If you have a web app and prefer to use a custom connection app you would need to create a new app as you can't change the app type once created.

If this does not help resolve your issue, please can you contact Xero Support via this [form](https://developer.xero.com/contact-xero-developer-platform-support) giving details of your app name and client id

Comment: That was it. I didn't create the apps so had no idea. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I didn't realize the Custom API was only available in the UK, Australia, and New Zealand. Since Canada isn't any of those I have to go with the OAuth flow anyway :(  To bad as the custom flow fits our use case and the OAuth flow does not.